# What type of tree is this that produces purple berries?

Tags: identification

Mom said it produces purple berries.
can I eat it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: At least once...

Comment: At least once what?

Comment: Eat it. Old mushroom collector's joke....

Comment: it could kill you or make you very sick

Comment: That's what the joke is referring to. You can eat everything *once*.

Comment: After you try it once, and it turns out to be poisonous you won't try anything else EVER!!!!, am I right?

Comment: Where are you located, that will help. To me it looks like a hack berry, but they grow in the south east of North America.

Comment: I'm in zone 4a MN

Comment: Yeah hackberry can grow there. I don't think it's a buckthorn. That's a branch, not a compound leaf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like [Common Buckthorn](https://mnfi.anr.msu.edu/invasive-species/CommonBuckthornBCP.pdf), though it's hard to see. Those berries would be a laxative... or it might be [chokecherries](https://igrow.org/gardens/gardening/chokecherries-and-buckthorn-whats-the-difference/), which are edible. Again, it's really hard to tell from the photo.

Chokecherries usually hang kind of separately from the leaves (compared with Common Buckthorn).

[image]

Edit- Taxonomic and other common names added for clarification:

*Rhamnus cathartica* (buckthorn, **common buckthorn** or purging buckthorn)

*Prunus virginiana* (bitter-berry, **chokecherry**, Virginia bird cherry, and western chokecherry)

Comment: Thanks, if it is buckthorn the city I live in would be guilty of introducing it., and it's growing between rows of pine trees.

Comment: If it is *Rhamnus cathartica*, don't eat it. From old book, it seems that it is very dangerously laxative (only strong farmers could handle it).

Comment: I can handle strong laxatives, I'll clog a 15 lbs suction toilet.

Comment: now that the berries are in season, can you tel me what it is?

Comment: It's still kind of hard to be sure but I think it's buckthorn. I edited my answer to include pictures showing what to look for. What you want to look at, is how the berries are connected. Are they in bunches or are they individually connected at the base of the leaves? Also, are the leaves serrated (like a saw) or smooth on the edges?